# Submit form is not triggger in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the form:

```
<form name="frmSelect" id="frmSelect" method="post" action="./abc.php">
  <input type="submit" value="To Confirm" name="To-Confirm" />   
  <span>Click</span>
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
span.onclick = function() {
  alert($('#frmSelect').length);

  $('#frmSelect').submit(function() {
    alert('abc');
    //var data = $("#frmSelect :input").serializeArray();
    //alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
    //OR 
    //document.frmSelect.submit(); <-- Not Working Too
    //var x = document.getElementsByName("To-Confirm").value; <-- Always "undefined".
  });
}
```

When I clicked on a `<span>` element, I am able to get the first alert with "1" (the length of form), but I am not able to get the second alert (which is abc).

p.s. there are many form elements but different name.

Comment: Why are you wrapping the submit function inside a span.onclick function?

Comment: What is `span`?

Comment: Why are you calling `onsubmit` event (in the jQuery way) inside an `onclick` event?

Comment: To submit a form when user click on the <Span>(instead of the actual submit button). And the <Span> is not always show on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

I think you shouldn't do it this way. 
Declare the comportement for the submit() function, and then raise the event submit as below...

```
$('#frmSelect').submit(function() {
    alert('abc');
});

span.onclick = function() {
    alert($('#frmSelect').length);
    $('#frmSelect').submit();
}
```

my 2 cents ;)

regards.

Comment: I think the form is having some problems when .submit(), so i use another method to  trigger the Submit button. When click on the Span it will trigger $('[name="To-Confirm"]').click();
Anyway thanks for urs 2 mil dollars!! ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to call the jQuery `submit` method:

1. To submit the form
2. To do something when the form is submitted

The way you call `submit` (with the callback argument), you are only trying to do the second thing, so you are *not* submitting the form. To also submit it, add the `submit` call without arguments.

Secondly, it is often a bad idea to assign an event handler within another event handler. So, only submit the form inside the click handler, but don't define the submit event handler there.

As a side note, why not keeping with the jQuery syntax also for the `span`?

```
$(span).click(function() {
    alert($('#frmSelect').length);
    $('#frmSelect').submit(); // <-- this submits the form
});

$('#frmSelect').submit(function() {
    alert('abc'); // <-- this executes when the form is submitted.
});
```

Comment: you should change $(span) into $("span")

Comment: @hasan, the OP had it as a variable (and it worked, since they get the `alert`), so I just used the same. I cannot assume that any `span` tag is intended. It could well be some designated one identified by that variable, maybe (or maybe not) in a loop that iterates over several of them. The OP has not clarified this.

Comment: I think the form is having some problems when .submit(), so i use another method to  trigger the Submit button. When click on the Span it will trigger $('[name="To-Confirm"]').click();
Anyway thanks for help!! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```js
$("span").on("click",function() {
    console.log("clicked");
    $('#frmSelect').submit(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="frmSelect" id="frmSelect" method="post" action="./abc.php">
      <input type="submit" value="To Confirm" name="To-Confirm" />   
      <span>Click</span>
</form>
```

Comment: I think the form is having some problems when .submit(), so i use another method to  trigger the Submit button. When click on the Span it will trigger $('[name="To-Confirm"]').click();
Anyway thanks for your help!! ;)